# I want to find the different rows where columnA of row1 = columnB of row2

Tags: sql

Lets say i have a table with three columns: id, colA & colB

I want to find the id's (and the rows) where one row's colA is equal to another row's colB.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this query:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.colB = t1.colA OR
          t2.colA = t1.colB
);
```

Comment: 'where one row's colA is equal to **another** row's colB'.

Comment: Thank you, but this query will return a row where colA = colB. I want to find the different rows, for exampe row26 & row45 where colA = colB

Comment: Sorry to both of you, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you very very much for the help, but unfortunately this doesnt work either. Basically what i want to have as a result is this: Lets say we have two rows and 3 columns. Column 1 is the id, column 2 and column 3. An example for a valid result is: ROW1: id1 | abc | .... | & ROW2: id2 | ... | abc. Column 2 of the ROW1 has the same value as Column 3 of ROW2. Sorry, but i don't know how to explain it more accurately. But, thanks again for the help!